# EXCEL Sheet Short cut to Update the value to particular cells

Tags: excel

I am new to Excel Sheet. have to Update the cells like below information. is anyone knows short to update the values to cells. please share the Information.

```
enter code here

In C9 Cell if I update the value 
C9 ==> 30431/31814/66335
it should automatically needs to update in a cell D9,E9,F9 like below,

D9 ==> 30431
E9 ==> 31814
F9 ==> 66335
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in D9,

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($C9, "/", REPT(" ", 99)), (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*99+1, 99))
```

Fill right to F9. Apply an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) as a wrapper to avoid errors.

[image: Pare values from text]

Comment: Thank You very much For your support

Comment: [Glad to hear you got sorted out quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).